# YouTube Search functionality Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using Google's Youtube API and it's pretty good.
I would like to know what is the best way to deal with search functionality in android?
I mean, as far as I know there isn't something related with making search or getting search results in android api. 
So how could I search for videos in YouTube and get the results and show them as a view.
What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference:

**GET API** `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`

You can try **Standalone API Explorer** for **Youtube Search Video**.

[Check this one](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), `part` parameter is compulsory.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'd try this Standalone API Explorer @Hiren Pater

Comment: @Shant11, are you able to fetch list form api or not ?

Comment: No, Can you tell me if there is a way ? @Hiren Patel